# How do you implement Generic_Sorting in Ada for a vector?

Tags: ada, gnat, gnat-gps, ada2012

I'm trying to do some basic translations of old C++ code from many moons ago to learn Ada, and I have been absolutely stumped on how to sort a vector using the built-in Generic_Sorting.  I haven't been able to find any concrete examples of it in action, the closest being a now-defunct Danish wiki article which looks like it would have had a full example but the archive didn't snatch it up: https://web.archive.org/web/20100222010428/http://wiki.ada-dk.org/index.php/Ada.Containers.Vectors#Vectors.Generic_Sorting

Here is the code as I thought it should work from the above link:

```ada
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;    use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;  use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors; use Ada.Containers;

procedure Vectortest is
   package IntegerVector is new Vectors
     (Index_Type   => Natural,
      Element_Type => Integer);
   package IVSorter is new Generic_Sorting;

   IntVec : IntegerVector.Vector;
   Cursor : IntegerVector.Cursor;
begin
   IntVec.Append(3);
   IntVec.Append(43);
   IntVec.Append(34);
   IntVec.Append(8);

   IVSorter.Sort(Container => IntVec);

   Cursor := IntegerVector.First(Input);
   while IntegerVector.Has_Element(Cursor) loop
      Put(IntegerVector.Element(Cursor));
      IntegerVector.Next(Cursor);
   end loop;

end Vectortest;
```

I've tried so many different combinations of `use` and `with` but all I can get are various error codes.  The above code gives `Generic_Sorting is not visible`, but when I try to explicitly state `with Ada.Containers.Vectors.Generic_Sorting` I get the error `"Ada.Containers.Vectors.Generic_Sorting" is not a predefined library unit`.  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, I'm sure it's a fundamental misunderstanding of the way Ada brings in packages, and I hope that nailing this down will help me understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Generic_Sorting` is an inner package to `Ada.Containers.Vectors` and cannot  be explicitly `with`ed (as you have discovered). And since `Ada.Containers.Vectors` is itself a generic package, `Generic_Sorting` is an inner package to the **instantiation** of `Ada.Containers.Vectors`. So you can reach it by prefixing with the name of the instance:

```
package IVSorter is new IntegerVector.Generic_Sorting;
```

Comment: That was it, thank you so much, I don't have enough rep to upvote you but I've accepted the solution, I can't tell you how much I appreciate it!  It all makes perfect sense, I knew I'd facepalm when I read the answer!